# ASP.NET / VB.NET - What is the equivalent of $_REQUEST of PHP in ASP.NET?

Tags: php, asp.net, vb.net, request

I'm just wondering, is there a way to get the `GET` parameters and `POST` parameters in just one function or `Collection` in ASP.NET? Like using `$_REQUEST` in PHP? I'm using VB.NET.

Comment: This also works `Request('varname')` , `Request.Item('varname')` , `Request.Params('varname')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Request["VariableName"]` (in C#) and `Request("VariableName")` (in VB) should work.

See [`HttpRequest.Item` indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.item.aspx):

> Name-value pairs are returned in the following order:
>
> 1. Query-string parameters.
> 2. Form fields.
> 3. Cookies.
> 4. Server variables.
>
> If the specified key is not found, then `null` is returned.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot, I'm using VB.NET, what is the  counterpart? Thanks!

Comment: `Request("VariableName")`??  You should learn to use the converter :) http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/.  C# and VB.Net use identical classes and libraries.  The only real difference is the syntax.

Comment: @mella - Wow! I didn't know such thing exists! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note:

`Request["xyz"]` gets it from cookies, querystring, form, or server variables

`Request.Parameters["xyz"]` does the same

`Request.QueryString["xyz"]` is just the querystring

`Request.Form["xyz"]` is just the form

Answer (score 0):

Sure is: `Request.QueryString` for GET, `Request.Form` for POST. You can specify a name to extract, i.e. `Request.QueryString("id")`, to get the "id" from the URL.

Comment: parameters in just **one function**